# Javascript : Which one is good practice that I define multiple variable or define one array and add multiple key?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Which one is best practice and why ?

```
var value1 = 100;
var value2 = 200;
var value3 = 300;

var myArray = {value1: 100, value2: 200, value3: 300};
```

Comment: it depends on the use. do you need an object or an access with variable keys?

Comment: best practice for what?  it is depended on certain situation.

Comment: Best practice would be to not use var, but const and let.

Comment: @KamilSolecki I have used const in my js file but its throw error like : https://prnt.sc/iwx558

Answer (score 0):

Contextually, if you group the variables into an object or map, I assume they are somehow related, which you may want to iterate through the variables or map the input to any output.

```
var global_counter = 0;
let obj = {a:'path1',b:'path2',c:'path3'};
let obj2 = [1,2,999,88];
function someHandleFunction(someInput){
    doGotoPath(obj[someInput]);
    console.log(obj2[global_counter++]);
}
```